# Why does accessing coefficients following estimation with nl require slightly different syntax than for other estimation commands?

Tags: syntax, stata

Following most estimation commands in Stata (e.g. `reg`, `logit`, `probit`, etc.) one may access the estimates using the `_b[ParameterName]` syntax (or the synonymous `_coef[ParameterName]`). For example:

```
regress y x
```

followed by

```
di _b[x]
```

will display the estimate of the coefficient of x. `di _b[_cons]` will display the coefficient of the estimated intercept (assuming the `regress` command was successful), etc.

But if I use the nonlinear least squares command `nl` I (seemingly) have to do something slightly different. Now (leaving aside that for this example model there is absolutely no need to use a NLLS regression):

```
nl (y = {_cons} + {x}*x)
```

followed by (notice the forward slash)

```
di _b[/x]
```

will display the estimate of the coefficient of x.

Why does accessing parameter estimates following `nl` require a different syntax? Are there subtleties to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"leaving aside that for this example model there is absolutely no need to use a NLLS regression": I think that's what you can't do here....

The question is about why the syntax is as it is. That's a matter of logic and a matter of history. Why a particular syntax was chosen is ultimately a question for the programmers at StataCorp who chose it. Here is one limited take on your question.

The main syntax for regression-type models grows out of a syntax designed for linear regression models in which by default the parameters include an intercept, as you know.

The original syntax for nonlinear regression models (in the sense of being estimated by nonlinear least-squares) matches a need to estimate a bundle of parameters specified by the user, which need not include an intercept at all. 
Otherwise put, there is no question of an intercept being a natural default; no parameterisation is a natural default and each model estimated by `nl` is *sui generis*.

A helpful feature is that users can choose the names they find natural for the parameters, within the constraints of what counts as a legal name in Stata, say `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`, `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. If you choose `_cons` for the intercept in `nl` that is a legal name but otherwise not special and just your choice; `nl` won't take it as a signal that it should flip into using `regress` conventions.

The syntax you cite is part of what was made possible by a major redesign of `nl` but it is consistent with the original philosophy.

That the syntax is different because it needs to be may not be the answer you seek, but I guess you'll get a fuller answer only from StataCorp; developers do hang out on Statalist, but they don't make themselves visible here.

Comment: Nick, thank you for taking the time to answer. But I don't see that the issue of *parameters broadly* (i.e. possibly nonlinear) vs. *slopes* / *coefficients* / *specifically linear parameters* really addresses my question: Both `regress` (for example) and `nl` use names to label parameter estimates. The need for a separate syntax to access the parameters so labeled is confusing and poorly documented. Perhaps there are reasons for it. Are there? :)

Comment: You'll have to ask StataCorp to go deeper, I think. Despite certain imperatives on syntax and firm conventions on many style issues, there remains room for programmer caprice. `nl` as I recall was originally user-written and that may linger. I don't agree with "poorly documented".

Comment: Fair enough. I guess by "poorly documented," I mean this special syntax requisite for `nl` does not appear in `help _variables` nor in the "Accessing coefficients and standard errors" portion of the **[U]** pdf, nor in `help nl` nor in `help nl_postestimation`. That qualifies as "poorly" in my book.

Comment: We all use negative words in such situations. But the alternative that all quirks  should be documented everywhere we might want to read about them would, however, just make the manuals longer and more confusing. Have you ever in teaching stopped yourself explaining a complication because your explanation was already longer and more difficult than students wanted to hear?

Comment: Yes. But always with a pointer to another time/resource to address this. Sta is very well documented overall in my experience. This specific issue seems odd, hence my question. :) "Poorly documented" I used specifically to refer to 'how one would access `nl` estimates'.

Comment: Send in an email with suggestions to StataCorp tech-support. They will know where to forward it.